# Percorrer uma lista dentro de outra Lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Olá eu sou iniciante em Python e gostaria de saber se tem como percorre uma lista dentro de outra lista, eu tentei fazer um exemplo, mais tá dando esse erro: "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable", se alguém puder me ajudar, desde já agradreço

```
result = ['spam', 1, ['Brie', 'Roquefort', 'Pol le Veq'], [1, 2, 3]]
for i in range (len(result)): # procurar em todas as listas internas
for j in range (i): 
    print(result[i][j])
```

Answer (score 2):

Este erro ocorre, porque você está tentando percorrer um número.

Utilizando o seu exemplo, ele tenta iterar os elementos 'spam' e '1'. Como eles não são uma lista, ocorre o erro.

Uma maneira de resolver este problema é colocando uma verificação antes de percorrer os itens internos.

```
result = ['spam', 1, ['Brie', 'Roquefort', 'Pol le Veq'], [1, 2, 3]]
for i in result:
    print(i)
    if type (i) == list:
       for j in i:
           print(j)
```

Eu mudei um pouco a maneira que eu faço a iteração, mas é possível utilizar a sua maneira de percorrer as listas.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda!